# KeyError.gnuhealth.inpatient.registration

Tags: keyerror, tryton

I am using Tryton's GNU Health.

I am facing a KeyError exception for the `"gnuhealth.inpatient.registration"` model in `health` module when I try to run the module. Others modules run fine, e.g. the `health_inpatient` module which depends on the `health` module as written in tryton.cfg file inside the `health_inpatient` module.

How is this possible? How can this be fixed?

Comment: What version of Tryton are you using? Can you share an exception stacktrace? Does that happen when activating the module, when booting the webserver, when connecting a client... when?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall the module, or maybe the error is inconsistence with the gnuhealth-client.